# Php failed to see files being uploaded after setting up LAMP on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed ubuntu with LAMP successfully on Linode. Before that, all my websites were hosted in godaddy. Everything works fine as well as Localhost with XAMPP.

However, with this new server @ Linode ; after i have uploaded all my PHP files to server and then started to upload products;

**mysql has been inserted but my abc.com/img folder is empty!!!**

```
require "../db/order.php";
$order=new order();

$allowed=['image/jpeg','image/png','image/gif'];

if(empty($_FILES['photos']['name'][0])){

    echo "<h1>plz select photos</h1>";

}else{

    foreach ($_FILES['photos']['type'] as $abc){

        if(!in_array($abc,$allowed)){
            echo '
            <div style="    margin: auto;
                width: 60%;
                border: 1px solid #ff0000;
                padding: 10px;">
            ';          

            echo '<p><a href="upload_picture.php">back to upload</a></p>';
            echo '</div>';

            $check=false;
        }else{
            $check=true;
        }
    }

    if($check==true){

        $path = "../../img/"; 
        for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['photos']['name']);$i++){
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$i],iconv("utf-8", "cp936", $path.$_FILES['photos']['name'][$i]));
            $img_name[]=$_FILES['photos']['name'][$i];
        }

        $order->add_img($img_name);

    }
}
```

**php.ini**

I have changed from

```
;upload_tmp_dir
```

to

```
upload_tmp_dir =/tmp
```

But it still doesn't work. Anyone can help ?

Comment: Can your webserver account see/access `/tmp`

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes! i can use FTP to see it with  root

Comment: The web server should not be running using the `root` account!!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly -_-... so it has to do with this "root" account problem ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why your file might not have uploaded.

First, I suggest using `is_uploaded_file()` before `move_uploaded_file()` to see if your file really arrives at the server.

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
    // move the file
} else {
    echo 'file not uploaded';
}
```

Have you got `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your HTML form tag?

Is `file_uploads = On` in php.ini?

How about `upload_max_filesize`?

Comment: it has nothing wrong with my php coding i think ?  If there is sth wrong with the coding, it shoudn't work in Localhost + Godaddy hosting. I think it has to do with my VPS setting or sth related

Comment: yes, i agree. it looks like the problem could be due to server configuration. both `file_uploads` and `upload_max_filesize` are PHP configuration in the php.ini file. have a look at the settings of these - they're a likely cause.

Comment: if you are using PHP7 (and your config is Ubuntu 16 default), you'll find php.ini at /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

Comment: yes. file_uploads  and upload_max_filesize   are ON and 2M .

Comment: what are the permissions on $path? `is_writable()` might be useful.